# Change font-size When Selection is made

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to change the font-size in a div when someone selects a different font size.

Here is my code which I know is working because I added an alert to it. The only thing not working is it changing the font size.

CSS:

```
.heading {
font-size:18px;
 }
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$('#htsize').on('change', function (e) {
var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
var valueSelected = this.value;
$(".heading").css("font-size", valueSelected);
});
```

HTML:

```
<SELECT id="htsize" name="htsize" style="width:100px; font-size:10px;">
<option value=""> SELECT ONE </option>
<option value="12">12px</option>
<option value="13">13px</option>
<option value="14">14px</option>
<option value="15">15px</option>
<option value="16">16px</option>
<option value="17">17px</option>
<option value="18">18px</option>
<option value="19">19px</option>
<option value="20">20px</option>
<option value="21">21px</option>
<option value="22">22px</option>
<option value="23">23px</option>
<option value="24">24px</option>
<option value="25">25px</option>
<option value="26">26px</option>
<option value="27">27px</option>
<option value="28">28px</option>
<option value="29">29px</option>
<option value="30">30px</option>
</select>

<div id="headline2" class="heading" style="position: relative; zindex: 99; width: 220px; padding: 5px; color: #ffffff; text-align: center;"></div>
```

I just can't figure out what is wrong.

Comment: `.css("font-size", valueSelected + "px")`. You forgot `+ "px"`.

Comment: You already seem to have px in your option values. Did you edit your question? Why people are suggesting to add px? Is your problem solved?

Comment: @PankajShukla the px is not in the value is in the display

Comment: Yeah, sorry! I meant did you not have it in display when you posted the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add `px` to the every option value or `valueSelected`+`'px'`

Answer (score 4):

You are missing the "px" from your value. So you can add it to the values of your dropdown or append it in your script like so:

```js
$('#htsize').on('change', function(e) {
  var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
  var valueSelected = this.value + "px";
  $(".heading").css("font-size", valueSelected);
});
```

```css
.heading {
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<SELECT id="htsize" name="htsize" style="width:100px; font-size:10px;">
<option value=""> SELECT ONE </option>
<option value="12">12px</option>
<option value="13">13px</option>
<option value="14">14px</option>
<option value="15">15px</option>
<option value="16">16px</option>
<option value="17">17px</option>
<option value="18">18px</option>
<option value="19">19px</option>
<option value="20">20px</option>
<option value="21">21px</option>
<option value="22">22px</option>
<option value="23">23px</option>
<option value="24">24px</option>
<option value="25">25px</option>
<option value="26">26px</option>
<option value="27">27px</option>
<option value="28">28px</option>
<option value="29">29px</option>
<option value="30">30px</option>
</select>

<div id="headline2" class="heading" style="">My Headline</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add px as the following code:

```
$('#htsize').on('change', function (e) {
    var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
    var valueSelected = this.value;
    $(".heading").css("font-size", valueSelected + 'px');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

$(".heading").css("font-size", valueSelected `+ 'px'`);

https://jsfiddle.net/ffpxgqy2/

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the "px" on the css font-size value! Here it's working -

```
<h1>Hello, World!</h1>

<select>
<option value="12">Default</option>
<option value="14">14 PX</option>
<option value="16">16 PX</option>
<option value="18">18 PX</option>
<option value="20">20 PX</option>
</select>

$("select").on("change", function (e) {
    var optionSelectedValue;
    $( "select option:selected" ).each(function() {
      optionSelectedValue = $( this ).val();
    });
    $("h1").css("font-size", optionSelectedValue + "px");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

### Try this

```
<SELECT id="htsize" name="htsize" style="width:100px; font-size:10px;">
<option value=""> SELECT ONE </option>
<option value="12">12px</option>
<option value="13">13px</option>
<option value="14">14px</option>
<option value="15">15px</option>
<option value="16">16px</option>
<option value="17">17px</option>
<option value="18">18px</option>
<option value="19">19px</option>
<option value="20">20px</option>
<option value="21">21px</option>
<option value="22">22px</option>
<option value="23">23px</option>
<option value="24">24px</option>
<option value="25">25px</option>
<option value="26">26px</option>
<option value="27">27px</option>
<option value="28">28px</option>
<option value="29">29px</option>
<option value="30">30px</option>
</select>

<div id="headline2" class="heading" style="">My Headline</div>
```

*Jquery*

```
 $('#htsize').change(function(event){
      var optval= $(this).val();
      var optpx= optval + 'px';
      $("#headline2").css("font-size", optpx);
    });
```